# How do I safely caramelize honey without fully burning it?

Tags: honey, caramelization

**Background:**
I am going to make a bochetomel, which is a type of mead that utilizes partly caramelized honey to impart a smokey/slightly burnt taste to the finished product.
The honey I have bought for this was expensive local produce, and I would like to avoid ruining it!

**Question(s):**
What is the best way to go about caramelizing honey? If I were to make an uninformed attempt, I'd just whack it in a saucepan and gradually heat it...
Is there a better method? Is it worth adding a little water to help stop it burning?

Finally, how will I know when the honey is caramelized? I have heard rumors of a 'soft ball stage' of caramelization that is ideal for brewing... does anyone have any experience with this that can confirm this exists?

Comment: I fully agree with Jefromi's answer but that said I can't help but critique the statement in the question it self that the "soft ball stage" is best for brewing. Yeast will be happy as long as there is sugar, anything but incinerating the sugar into carbon will leave the yeast in a happy state... I'm probably being overly picky but just to be clear the particular candy-stage probably has to do with taste preference rather than than the actually ability to brew, and while the initial author of the recipe probably thought the soft ball stage was ideal, individual preference will certainly vary

Comment: One thing I shall add from personal experience making italian meringue with honey: use a big pot. Honey will foam a LOT once it starts boiling, and while using lower heat/constant supervision are both important, I would still recommend using a pot with nice tall sides...

Comment: Just a hint - consider first learning   how  to do   it  on  similar,  but   cheaper  honey.  Caramelized  honey is   pretty  nice addition  to  winter  tea or Christmas cakes :)

Comment: @Quaternion Apologies for not being too clear in my question! I was asking whether anyone could clarify whether the stage existed, rather than whether it was the 'best' stage to use to brew with, and as per the two current answers it does :)

Comment: @Korthalion I thought as much but just wanted to make sure you didn't take the recipe as gospel. I've made mead quite a few times but have never tried to caramelise the sugar but being a bit obsessive about wanting to know the effects of things (like finding the statistically ideal sugar to acid ratio in cider; which as studies show the average ratio for what is ideal differs between Europe and North America as well as by sex) anyways I would take very small batches and using a candy thermometer record the values pushing the limit... the trouble is that

Comment: in brewing, it is hard to determine the taste of the final product from the initial. Caramel, Smoke, and Charcol are pretty invariant flavours but still even if you near char the honey you might end up with a great hit. Also you can caramelise the honey to different levels in the same batch. And a blow torch can be a quick short cut to smoke and char, as in creme brulee (although I would reducing to sugar first, like maple sugar). Also because mead has a much larger ageing window than beer (similar to wine) going with a range of 4L vs a typical 22L will let you hone results faster...

Comment: @Quaternion Thanks for the advice :) I'm going to set two 1 gallon batches off using the same honey, but only one will be caramelized. That will hopefully allow me to judge the effect the caramelization has had on the finished product.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A candy thermometer is pretty much always the answer when it comes to candymaking, which includes caramelizing sugar.

Assuming the soft ball stage is indeed the best for brewing, all you have to do is keep track of the temperature: the [soft ball stage is at 112-116C/234-241F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_making#Sugar_stages).

While you can certainly buy specialized candy thermometers (they often have clips to attach to the pot), all you really need is a thermometer that's accurate in that range and can be easily dipped into your pot. (That is, don't use some old glass thermometer not meant for candy, but a kitchen thermometer with a metal probe is fine, whether or not it was sold as a candy thermometer.) Make sure that you have it in the liquid, not touching the bottom of the pot.

Note that this is *well* short of burning; there are several other stages hotter than that. So just don't use excessive heat, and keep an eye on it, and you won't have any disasters. This is also likely why people are a bit suspicious that this is the right stage to aim for: table sugar doesn't start browning until you're past *all* the candymaking stages, up to ~170C/338F. However, table sugar is pure sucrose, while honey has a lot of imperfections and is monosaccharide fructose and glucose, so it likely caramelizes much faster, so this may well be a good stage/temperature range.

There's also a way to test without a thermometer, but it's more difficult to get right on the first try. The stage is named the soft ball stage because if you take a bit of the syrup at that stage and drop it into cool water to quickly cool it, you'll end up with a soft, smooth ball/lump.

---

Adding water doesn't really help here. The temperatures are well above boiling, so the water is really just there to help get things going initially; the water helps ensure that there's something in contact with the whole bottom of the pot (no hot spots to form), and lets things flow around a bit, so you get to melted sugar with less fuss. Since you're starting with honey, you're already fine. Even if it starts out thick, it'll rapidly get thinner as it heats. All that will happen if you add water is that it'll take longer for all the water to cook off so that the temperature can rise to where you want.

---

Finally, this isn't what you asked, but if your goal is *flavor*, you can also simply heat *slowly* until it starts to brown/darken a bit and smell good, and then immediately remove the pot from the heat. The "slowly" is really important, because  once the water is gone, the temperature will rise rapidly. You can still use a thermometer to help out with this plan, by watching for the temperature to pass 100C and start to increase more quickly; at that point you want to make sure the heat is very low and you're ready to move the pot.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Jefromi! Very informative and answered all facets of my query.
My thermometer I ordered online arrived yesterday so I'm clear to give this an attempt soon! I have made bonfire toffee before, so now you've mentioned it I think I understand what the soft-ball stage is :)

Comment: Bear in mind the answer above is for caramelised sugar however, not honey.  If you are looking for a smokey flavour i would smoke an open jar of honey, but both answers are for sugar, not honey, so beware, as your honey may wel lend up ruined in both use cases.

Comment: @GMasucci Honey is sugar and water. This will work. Yes, you will lose some of the delicate, aromatic flavors, but the OP's stated goal is to get the honey to the soft ball stage, and this is how you do that.

Comment: Honey is most definitely **not** sugar and water, different physical and chemical properties altogether, different burn points sugar melts at 186 degrees C, honey is between 40 and 50 degrees C if crystallised or melted at room temperature otherwise. And about a million other reasons why they cant be treated the same, foremost of which is the loss of flavour which is the main criteria in the OPs question.As presented in your answer this is how you burn honey.

Comment: @GMasucci The melting temperature you try to make is not meaningful: you're comparing the melting point of pure, solid sugar with a "melting" point of honey, a saturated or super-saturated solution of sugar in water, which is *already a liquid*. If you want a vaguely fair comparison, dissolve the table sugar in water first. I invite you to write a different answer if you like.

Comment: It bears stressing to check that the thermometer is compatible (if not a specialized candy thermometer). While less common now, mercury thermometers designed for taking body or ambient temperature will ususally not have a scale that runs into candy temperatures and will explode if you get them that hot.  Naturally you want to avoid this, especially with mercury thermometers.  Candy thermometers also usually have a double-wall design that encloses the inner thermometer in case it does explode (to make it safer).  It's really best to use the right tool, tbh.

Comment: @J... I did say it needs to be able to measure in that range. I'm not sure if I've seen kitchen thermometers that cover that range that wouldn't be safe. They're generally metal probes.

Comment: @Jefromi You did, it's just that given the explosion hazard of using a glass, non-kitchen thermometer for candy work I felt it was worth at least noting that hazard.  Sometimes people read "any old thermometer will do" and get themselves into trouble.  This is just one of those times where it's worthwhile to take a bit of extra care.

Answer (score 11):

In the event that you aren't keen on buying/using a candy thermometer, I thought I'd add some additional information.

The '**soft ball**' stage in candy-making is the stage where the sugar has thoroughly *melted* - meaning it's no longer granulated. The non-thermometer testing method is to drop a small amount of the mixture into cool water, and see if it forms a soft ball.

When making a generic caramel, you're mixing butter and sugar, and heating until the sugar melts. If you add this mixture to water prematurely, it separates into sugar crystals and oil. If the sugar is melted, the mixture hardens without separating - the liquid sugar reforms to a uniform, connected, solid.

**But this doesn't seem like what you actually want...**

You want to impart a small amount of 'smokiness' to the flavor. Merely getting to the soft ball stage will, yes, melt your sugar crystals and change the consistency of your honey, but you'll need to go further to actually change the flavor.

As Jefromi said, the key to not ruining your honey will be to add heat slowly and evenly. Use a low-heat setting and continuously sample the mixture. Once actual caramelized sugars start to form (a portion of the sugar burns), you should notice it in the smell and taste. **You have to keep the ratio of burned : unburned sugars reasonable.** And your brew might benefit from a more *pungent* caramel than you'd want to eat plain, but that's a decision you'll have to make for yourself.

Good luck, and happy brewing.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, good advice concerning sampling and smokiness levels :)

Comment: It's not necessarily true that there'd be no flavor change at the soft ball stage. Remember, honey isn't just sugars, and the soft ball temperature is plenty high enough for Maillard browning to occur. It's possible that this style calls for those flavors, rather than those of "pure" caramelization.

Comment: @Sneftel My experience with caramel is limited to fudge making, and this is the first I've heard of the Maillard reaction. A cursory search showed that the Maillard reaction occurs between 140 to 165°C, while the soft-ball stage seems to occur at 118°C... I'd like to improve my knowledge on the subject, so please let me know if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: "When making a generic caramel, you're mixing butter and sugar" - really? Most   recipes I've   read called for sugar and sometimes  small   additions  of citric acid etc, but never fat. Caramel *sauce*, or sometimes caramel *candy*  on   the other hand, calls  for fat

Comment: @Mołot As I replied to Sneftel above, my caramel experience is only as it relates to candy (specifically fudge) - so I do think of 'generic caramel' as the product I get when I heat butter and sugar. You're welcome to suggest an edit to the answer if you feel you can better clarify.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are still looking for caramelised honey guides, and not caramelised sugar guides, I have found the following:

- [lemony caramelised honey](https://honeyandspice.wordpress.com/how-to/caramelize-honey/)
- [plain caramelised honey](https://www.bee-america.com/content/can-honey-taste-even-better)
- [another plain caramelised honey recipe](https://ifood.tv/techniques/179543-how-to-caramelize-honey)

And to add the smoky flavour, first make smoky honey:

- [recipe here](https://www.eatthelove.com/2015/02/smoked-honey/#recipe)

Personally for smoking I would do it in the oven with wood-chips/herbs of the appropriate flavour.  The simplest instructions for home smoking without a custom smoker I have found are [here](http://www.downthecove.com/food-drink/home-smoking/) though there are many YouTube videos showing how to add smoked flavour using a normal oven and a baking tray.

I have added [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3ZxHl3TaIU) as an example on how to do the smoking, all you would do is swap the meat with honey in an ovenproof container.

Solid sugar melts at 186 degrees C, sugar and water at about 132 degrees C, honey is between 40 and 50 degrees C if crystallised, or if non crystallised then it is melted at room temperature.

So be very careful as to how hot you go or your expensive honey will end up being expensive char.

For the smoking I would sduggest a slight modification to the norm for honey: use an ovenproof container the rest as per the meat, only put the oven on to about 50 degrees C though, and set fire to the wood-chips yourself, letting them smoulder (a chefs torch works for this) I have used similar techniques when making uncooked ham (for cooked, just use the way that is shown in the video).  I am not sure what temperatures you heat the honey to before use in mead-making however, if they are higher you could use them instead of the 50 degrees C limit above.

The main point to note though is that its a two stage procedure to get smoky and caramelised.

You mention you are making a bochetomel, so have [included the simplest guide](http://www.winemakingtalk.com/Bochet-Mead-Carmelize-in-Wine-Winemaking-Talk.html) I could find on that too, as it has another way to caramelise the honey.
( I am thinking of using that in conjunction with [this](https://www.growforagecookferment.com/how-to-make-elderberry-mead/) to make an eldeberry bochetomel for my wife).

Comment: Those guides are good advice. Note, though, that they are almost certainly going *past* the soft ball stage, to temperatures hotter than mentioned in my answer. Honey does have more imperfections, which speeds up caramelization, but "golden brown", "darker", and "nutty aroma" are all signs you're well past the soft ball stage *and* the rest of the candymaking stages, on into caramelization. So, if you're concerned about losing delicate aromatics, those are actually *worse* than aiming for soft ball stage.

Comment: Agreed will edit to suit:)

Comment: I should also say that the mention of melting point still doesn't seem to be relevant. Caramelization is a set of chemical reactions, it's not a phase transition, and the same is true of burning. The melting point doesn't tell you the temperature it'll caramelize or burn at.

Comment: You also don't have to get sugar+water to 132C to get it to "melt". When you make candy, you start out with sugar+water (and possibly other things), and heat til it's all dissolved (just liquid), and then heat to the desired temperature. The *lowest* candymaking stage, thread, is at 110C. And that stage makes syrup, i.e. something that's liquid at room temperature, so the melting point is actually pretty similar to honey. Fortunately your answer doesn't appear to depend on this - I think you could just remove that paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

My original comment was based on reading, this is based on doing.

I tried the slow cooker (crock pot) method and am happy with the results.  I added 3 pounds of honey, making sure that it took up less than a 1/3 of the crock pot, and kept the crock pot on low.  I did stir and scrape the sides, but I'm not convinced that was really necessary.

I used the *take a little bit out, drop it on a paper plate* method of determining how far through the process I was (and of course, once the sample cooled, tasting it).  The color didn't really change until about 4 hours.  At 4.5 hours, the flavor was sufficiently like caramel that I decide to stop versus continuing to the "toasted marshmallow" stage.

On the low setting, the heat was low enough that I never got more than an 1/8th of an inch of foam on the top.  I had placed the entire crock pot into a plastic box just in case.  Thankfully, that wasn't needed (this time).

After unplugging it, I waited for the temperature to drop below the boiling point of water (candy themometer is handy here), and then stirred in a half gallon of water.  I then ladled the caramelized honey water into the 2 one-gallon fermenters.

I was pleasantly surprised at the ease of clean-up. I was expecting a nightmare, but it was exceptionally painless.  After moving the honey to the fermenters, I just had to rinse the crock pot ceramic and use a damp sponge.  Easiest crock pot cleanup I've ever had.

I ended up using about 3 pounds of caramelized honey, just under 4 pounds of raw honey, split between two one-gallon fermenters.  The specific gravity ended up being 1136 and 1132.  The two fermenters are bubbling away as I type.

It's too early in the brew cycle for regrets, but I have since read that the caramel flavor will probably be removed during the fermentation process.  I started wondering if I should have caramelized all of the honey, but read where someone had, and they wished they had gone 50/50.

I wonder if next time I should plan on having the bochet go dry and then back sweeten with caramelized honey (cheating?).

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party, but have been searching for similar content (obviously).  One of the suggestions that I read was to use a slow cooker (crock pot) on low setting.  It will start to caramelize after about 4 hours and you can continue, depending on how much caramelization you want, probably stopping before 6 hours.

Things to keep in mind include:

- because of foaming, have the initial honey take up less than 1/3 of the total volume
- stir, less frequently at first, more as you get to the 3+ hour mark
- while stirring, be sure to scrape any honey off the sides

Personally, while making a bochetomel, I would go with half caramelized and half raw honey.  I would use inexpensive honey for the caremalization since the heating will destroy the subtleties, but then use the more expensive local honey for raw.

Curious as to what you did and how it turned out.

Answer (score 0):

Using the microwave to caramelize honey works great. You can achieve any grade of caramelization just by adjusting the power and time. The only tricky part is to keep an eye on foam creation. Whenever the liquid builds up bubbles you have to wait some time until you continue microwaving.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea, as I wouldn't then be able to stir it nor regulate the temperature.

Comment: But the degree of caramellization. Also it is somehow self regulating and the only way without carbonization.

Comment: A little carbonization is what I'm after. I'm trying to impart a slightly smokey flavour to the honey/finished product.

Answer (score 0):

I used a pressure cooker and three large jars. It was a ton easier than standing over a pot stirring for hours. I think I got the info on it from the homebrew forums, check there or google it, there are a few how tos out there, but it's pretty straight forward if you've used a pressure cooker for canning before...